# I need to trigger Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup from textbox updated externally

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have a form that gets updated from a web page scrapping. 
One of the entries is missing and so I use a value from a textbox to do a vlookup to get the missing info and update the empty textbox.
None of the event methods fire automatically!

```
Private Sub envelope_afterupdate()
On Error Resume Next

MsgBox ("test")
name_env.text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(envelope.text,    Worksheets("DATA_name").Range("a1:b334"), 2, False)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

  '  MsgBox "currName not found" ''optional, no need to do anything
End If

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure your vlookup is actually returning a value?

Comment: Yes the textbox works perfectly , however I found a simple way to do what I want by putting the update vlookup in the code used to extract the data in the first place. Just had to change the way I address them.

Answer (score 0):

I simply put the vlookup in my data extraction code!

Form1.name_env = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(form1.envelope, Worksheets("DATA_name").Range("a1:b334"), 2, False)

Pete